shedule alarm using AlarmManager not working

i working on an app that needs to set an alarm for a user specified period in the future.
now there are a lot of example out there so, should not be to hard should it :-(
Now this is still not the most pretty code as in the use of resource.
To set the alarm
fun setAlarm(offsetDay: Int, hour: Int, min: Int) {
    Log.i("XXX", "setAlarm start method")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "need min android O", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    } else {
        val alarmManager = mContext.getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)
        val alarmIntent  = Intent(mContext, CustomAlarmReceiver::class.java).let {
                                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 222, it, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)  }

        Log.i("XXX", "manager and intent set")

        // todo: on the real phone version remove the timezone for the now-part it will then take the default timezone
        val now = LocalDateTime.now(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Amsterdam").toZoneId())
        val tempTarget = LocalDateTime.of(
            now.toLocalDate(),
            LocalTime.of(hour, min)
        )
        val target = tempTarget.plusDays(offsetDay.toLong())
        val duration = Duration.between(now, target)

        Log.i("XXX", "duration calculated: ${duration.toMillis()}")
        if (if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                alarmManager.canScheduleExactAlarms()
            } else {
                true
            }
        ) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                                  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + duration.toMillis(),
                                  alarmIntent
                                 ) 
            Log.i("XXX" "setExact completed")
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    }
}

Now everything runs without any error but no alarm is set.
it is also hard to find if an alarm is set because examples where the create the intent with FLAG_NO_CREATE does not work over android 12 and i was not able to find another way to check this.
using the command "adb shell dumpsys alarm" gives so much data it is nearly impossible to find anything but after a long long search i am pretty sure my alarm is not in the list.
so 2 questions for now:

what is wrong with my code to set an alarm?
how do you check if "the" alarm is set in android above 12?


Hope somebody can help
Update1
Updated the code (Log.i added) based on the question of dominicoder
The image below show no messages at all in the log except the once i write my self. The log also shows the duration i calculate is a positive number. The way of working is copied from the android help.
This link: shedule alarms (example with: "Wake up the device to fire a one-time (non-repeating) alarm in one minute") only difference is that i used an 'exact' (tried the same as the example but same result).


Have you debugged your code to confirm that the values you are calculating for the assorted time values are correct? Have you looked in LogCat for any errors reported by the system when you call this code?

@dominicoder: updated my question to reflect your question. In short no errors in the log and the calculated value is a positive number that at least seems to be close the the amount of millisec i expect.
